# Vlookup this text string

Tags: excel, vlookup

I would like to know how to go about this. Imagine a text string such as this

```
/search/p300_action/search?catid=1&makeid=0&modelid=0&locid=1&yearmin=min&yearmax=max&pricemin=min&pricemax=max&conid=0&displaylocal=1&searchtext=Enter+Keyword(s)+/+AutoID
```

and I want to break down the info into respective categories such as makeid, modelid, yearmax etc... and relate the relevant categories into another page that have values for it. E.g lets say makeid: 0, 1, 2, 3 .... stands for makename: HP, samsung, compaq, acer respectively.

Kindly give me a simplified way to go about this.

Comment: 1. Not related to facebook, right ? by `vlookup`, you mean you're working in Excel ? in VBA or in Excel formula?

Comment: It's in excel. Sorry for not including that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all clear what you require (and I'm not alone!) but maybe Text To Columns (Delimited and Other: `&` as delimiter) then something like `=VLOOKUP(VALUE(RIGHT(B1,1)),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Your suggestion was quite useful but it will be quite difficult if one were to work with long columns of test strings especially as they do not bare the same set/format of text strings. I would want a formula that can auto breakdown the strings in such a way that I only need to copy and paste into relevant cells to get my results for subsequent tasks. I hope you do understand? Expecting a positive reply.